# Can i use TextView.setText() inside of activity class if i pass MainActivity to this class?

Tags: java, android

I have following Activity:

```
       public class MapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    
    TextView mDistance;
 public Navigation navi = new Navigation(this, this);
    
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDistance = findViewById(R.id.distance2);
    
    }
    
   
    }
```

and class Navigation:

```
public class Navigation  {

 public Navigation(Context context, MapActivity mapActivity) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mapActivity = mapActivity;

    }

 public void updateText(String text){
        mapActivity.mTravelTime.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Can i update mDistance using mapActivity.mTravelTime.setText(text); from navi class ? or i need to do it on runOnUIThread ?

Thanks you

Comment: Bear in mind this is probably a very bad idea. You do not control your activity lifecycle, Android does; by passing it to your Navigation, and having a hard reference, you're potentially preventing all the activity (and its views) to be destroyed when they should. Or to point to an activity that was destroyed to begin with, causing IllegalState/NullPointer exceptions.

Comment: Please consider adding all relevant code or better a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the thread that is executing the call to updateText(text). If you're on the main thread, you'll be good. If you're on a background thread, you'll want to use runOnUIThead(). If you're not sure, assume a background thread to be safe.